# debug react native app from chrome on windows machine

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I started exploring react-native. One thing which I want is should able to debug my app from chrome. I am having prior experience to cordova. Cordova renders app in chrome web view. I understand that with react-native it is not possible because react-native doesn't render app on web view.

There is an option react-native "debug in chrome". When I click this option, attached screenshot is getting opened. I enabled "pause on exception."

But nothing is happening. I am unable to see my app code at all.
I like to do step by step debugging. Is it possible? If so can some one tell how to do this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely examine the source code, set breakpoints, etc in Chrome.

In the Sources menu, select `debuggerWorker.js` and then you should be able to see your project tree.

Any `console.log` in your code will print to the browser too. But I find the breakpoint inspection most helpful.

[image: Select debuggerWorker.js]

Answer (score 0):

this is simple as you were doing in cordova.
try to put debugger; statement in your code while in debug mode.
It will set the breakpoint and you can then debug your application. No need to find out your files in debuggerWorker.js